# Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo): How to add a remote Maven 2 repository mirror

Tags: eclipse, maven

I recently installed Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) and now a wanted to start a new project using the integrated Maven plugins.


Problem is, I can't download any dependencies from the central maven 2 repository http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

After creating a new simple Maven project (without an archetype), i constantly get these Error messages:

- *Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
  CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: ArtifactResolutionException: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 is not available in the local repository. pom.xml /JAVA   line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem*
- *Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
  Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3 pom.xml /JAVA   line 1  Maven Build Problem*
- *Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
  Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)  pom.xml /JAVA   line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem*
- *Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
  Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile) pom.xml /JAVA   line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem*

Using an archetype doesn't work at all.

Am I right to just add another repository mirror to get the needed dependencies?

If so, how do I add another one?

---

**Update:** I wrote a *D:\Users\.m2\settings.xml* manually and the m2e-plugin recognized it correctly:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
          <id>dotsrc.org</id>
          <url>http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/maven2</url>
          <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Problem is: I can't find a complete mirror of the Maven central repository. I tried every single one I could find on the net, but all are missing some dependencies, archetypes, etc.

Any help out there?

Comment: @VonC: Thanks for the reply, but i already tried that and it didn't help, since i don't have a proxy problem. I still can connect to the marketplace and download/install other plugins. ... Although, i didn't find the maven _settings.xml_ to change the proxy settings... i guess, it uses the eclipse settings instead (so it should work).

Comment: Would that be related to http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/06/where-is-m2eclipse/ ? (and the fact the plugin is now called m2e)

Comment: @VonC: Well, i already downloaded the prepackaged Bundle (Eclipse & M2E) and that's what bothers me. I have these problems in this out-of-the-box bundle. :/

Comment: 'I wrote a settings.xml manually and the m2e-plugin recognized it correctly' - so what was in the settings file that fixed the problem? Please post an answer if you managed to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of [these](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mirrors+Repositories).

Comment: Tried.. but no one works / has the archetypes i need .... or I'm just too dumb to use it X-)

Comment: Is there any reason you are trying to use a proxy at all? I should be enough to use the US or UK mirror depending on your location. The would be to set up a Nexus instance a be your own proxy. This is what I do at home and at work.

Comment: @Micheal-O: Simple reason... my company uses a proxy for all internet traffic, so i'm pretty stuck here. I also had the idea of using nexus, but that can't be done so easily ... funny eh? ^^

Comment: Nexus is the perfect approach! I have the same situation and Nexus brought salvation. You should seriously consider Nexus. You and others are wasting their time in downloading the same artifacts over and over again.

Comment: ... that'll be another discussion with my Admin ^^ ... I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: IF this is done, you can point everyone's Maven settings to that Nexus instance. I'd be glad if you'd mark this as a correct answer.

Comment: @Gruber let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1627/discussion-between-michael-o-and-gruber)